# Why does an iterator of `ToString` items requires them to be `Display` also?

Tags: rust, traits, type-bounds

The following code:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B,
}

impl ToString for MyEnum {
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        match *self {
            Self::A => format!("A"),
            Self::B => format!("B"),
        }
    }
}

pub fn foo<I: ToString>(item: I) {
    println!("item: {}", item.to_string());
}

pub fn bar<I: ToString>(iter: impl Iterator<Item = I>) {
    iter.for_each(|item| println!("item: {}", item.to_string()))
}

fn main() {
    foo(MyEnum::A);
    bar([MyEnum::A, MyEnum::B].iter());
}
```

Produces the following compilation error:

```
error[E0277]: `MyEnum` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  --> src\bin\main6.rs:25:2
   |
25 |     bar([MyEnum::A, MyEnum::B].iter());
   |     ^^^ `MyEnum` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `MyEnum`
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Display` for `&MyEnum`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `ToString` for `&MyEnum`
note: required by a bound in `bar`
  --> src\bin\main6.rs:19:15
   |
19 | pub fn bar<I: ToString>(iter: impl Iterator<Item = I>) {
   |               ^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `bar`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

`bar` accepts iterators whose items implement `ToString`. `MyEnum` implements `ToString`, so `[MyEnum::A, MyEnum::B].iter()` is in fact an iterator of items that implement `ToString`.

`foo` and `bar` are very similar, in both the generic type `I` is replaced with `MyEnum`, so why is the trait bound `Display` required in `bar` but not in `foo`?

Comment: Note that `ToString` is automatically implemented for any type that implements `Display`. Consider implementing `Display` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[MyEnum::A, MyEnum::B].iter()` creates an iterator whose item is `&MyEnum`. `&MyEnum` does not implement `ToString`, only `MyEnum` does. This works:

```rust
enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B,
}

impl ToString for MyEnum {
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        match *self {
            Self::A => format!("A"),
            Self::B => format!("B"),
        }
    }
}

pub fn foo<I: ToString>(item: I) {
    println!("item: {}", item.to_string());
}

pub fn bar<I: ToString>(iter: impl Iterator<Item = I>) {
    iter.for_each(|item| println!("item: {}", item.to_string()))
}

fn main() {
    foo(MyEnum::A);
    bar([MyEnum::A, MyEnum::B].into_iter());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ba4c6455f7bd3341c0bc254498298747)

And if you want to accept any `&I` such that `I: Display`:

```rust
pub fn bar<'a, I: 'a>(iter: impl Iterator<Item = &'a I>) where I: ToString {
    iter.for_each(|item| println!("item: {}", item.to_string()))
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!